# we need to increment the stage property value till stage length array value in and object which is in task array on forward click

Tags: angular

// this is my html file

Create task

```
<div class="mt-50 layout-row">
  <div class="card outlined ml-20 mt-0" *ngFor="let tasks of stagesTasks;index as i;">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h4>{{this.stagesNames[i]}}</h4>
      <ul class="styled mt-50" [attr.data-test-id]="'stage-'+ i">
        <li *ngFor="let task of tasks; index as index;">
          <div class="li-content layout-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <span [attr.data-test-id]="generateTestId(task.name)+ '-name'">{{task.name}}</span>
              <div class="icons">
                <button class="icon-only x-small mx-2"
                        [attr.data-test-id]="generateTestId(task.name)+ '-back'">
                  <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
                </button>

                <button class="icon-only x-small mx-2"
                        [attr.data-test-id]="generateTestId(task.name)+ '-forward'" (click)="changeTaskState(task)">
                  <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
                </button>

                <button class="icon-only danger x-small mx-2"
                        [attr.data-test-id]="generateTestId(task.name)+ '-delete'">
                  <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

we need to increment the stage property  value till stage length  array value in and object which is in task array on forward click. ihave done increment using index value but didn't work
    import { renderFlagCheckIfStmt } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/template';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'kanban-board',
     templateUrl: './kanbanBoard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./kanbanBoard.component.scss']
 })
 export class KanbanBoard implements OnInit {
    tasks: Task[];
    stagesNames: string[];
    stagesTasks: any[]; //Only used for rendering purpose
    taskInput: string;
    taskname: string;
 ngOnInit() {
// Each task is uniquely identified by its name. 
// Therefore, when you perform any operation on tasks, make sure you pick tasks by names 
(primary key) instead of any kind of index or any other attribute.
this.tasks = [
  // { name: '0', stage: 0 },
  // { name: '1', stage: 0 },
  //{ name: this.taskInput, stage: 0 },
];
this.stagesNames = ['Backlog', 'To Do', 'Ongoing', 'Done'];
this.configureTasksForRendering();
}

 // this function has to be called whenever tasks array is changed to construct stagesTasks 
for rendering purpose
 configureTasksForRendering = () => {
 this.stagesTasks = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < this.stagesNames.length; ++i) {
  this.stagesTasks.push([]);
}
for (let task of this.tasks) {
  const stageId = task.stage;
  this.stagesTasks[stageId].push(task);
}

}

// Read input value on button click(create task button)
getTaskName() {
console.log("new task created", this.taskInput);
const taskname = this.taskInput;
console.log(taskname);
let task: any = { name: taskname, stage: 0 };

this.tasks.push(task);
// console.log(this.tasks);
this.configureTasksForRendering();
this.taskInput = "";

//  for (let name of this.tasks) {
//   const taskname = name.name;
//   this.stagesTasks[taskname].push(name);
// }

   }
  changeTaskState(i) {
   //console.log("forward works")

   // console.log(index);
    // console.log(this.tasks[index].stage);
     //this.tasks[index].stage++;
// console.log(this.tasks[index].stage);
// console.log(index);
// console.log(this.stagesTasks);
console.log(i);

console.log(i.stage);


//this.tasks[i].stage++;
//this.generateTestId(i)

this.configureTasksForRendering();

// for (let i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; ++i) {

// }
// for(let task of this.tasks ){

// }
  }


  generateTestId = (name) => {
  // console.log(name)
   //console.log(name.split(' ').join('-'));

  return name.split(' ').join('-');
 }
}
 //task interface
 interface Task {
  name: string;
  stage: number;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can see, you have commented the line which where you have written increment logic, still for your reference I have created basic snippet, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxquti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: stage is incremented but i have issue with index when the task moved to the second stage card